# C# Datatable data to chart

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a text file as a data source and made a datatable with all the data in it. Now i need to get data out of it create a chart.

Full datatable looks like this

```
datestamp   |    name_X_1      |    name_X_2      |    name_Y_1      |    name_Y_2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/199     |    somevalue     |    somevalue     |    somevalue     |    somevalue
1/2/199     |    somevalue     |    somevalue     |    somevalue     |    somevalue
```

Now I need to have all name_X_* values from the name_x_* columns from a certain time (which will be a variable from a calendar control).

This is how i need the data to be for the chart

```
datastamp   |    name_x_data        |    name_y_data
-------------------------------------------------------
1/1/199     |    name_X_1_value     |    name_y_1_value  
1/1/199     |    name_X_2_value     |    name_y_2_value
```

To make a bit more difficult, the name_X_* and name_y_* columns can vary (X and Y are the x and y axis values from a measurement and are always the same amount of columns). In one text file it's 10 columns and a other text file it could be 20. So I can't hardcode the column names. I need to filter them on name_X_ and name_Y_ and search on a specific date.

I could also store the number of columns. So if we could select on column number 2 till 10 for X and 10 till 20 for Y it would be awesome to. Its ok to have a administration on the text file in the database here i enter the amount of columns the text file has. So if someone has a option to use count it would work for me too.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

This is the code i made so far:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string[] columns = null;

string FileName = "C:\\datapath\\data.dat";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);

// create columns from text file and skip first few rows
if (lines.Count() > 2)
    {
        columns = lines[1].Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => x.Replace("\"", "")).ToArray();

        foreach (var column in columns)
            dt.Columns.Add(column);
    }

// add data to rows
for (int i = 2; i < lines.Count(); i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        string[] values = lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' }).Select(x => x.Replace("\"", "")).ToArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < values.Count() && j < columns.Count(); j++)
            dr[j] = values[j];

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

// Columns filter (under construction) (this is the part i need to be not hard coded)

string[] selectedColumns = new[] { "TIMESTAMP", "sensor_X_001", "sensor_X_002" };

DataTable dt2 = new DataView(dt).ToTable(false, selectedColumns);
    
// Date filter (under construction)
// string s = "2014-05-21 13:05:00";
// DataRow foundRow = dt2.Tables["TIMESTAMP"].Rows.Find(s);

// data to grid 
this.GridView1.DataSource = dt2;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is a very well written question, unfortunately though it is off-topic as it is too broad. That means you are asking for to much to be done for you. I recommend you try something for yourself and then include that code in your questions. Try to focus on a more specific problem, rather than a full specification

Comment: @apomene did you read EVERYTHING?

Comment: Ok, let me edit my post with what i got so far :)

Comment: @Reniuz the truth is I did not

Comment: @apomene It is clear that you did not by your first comment :)

Comment: Added the code i already made. Hope that helps with pointing me into the right direction. Any help would be appreciateit :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and thought i should share it :)

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Columns.Add("datestamp", typeof(String));
result.Columns.Add("name_x_data", typeof(String));
result.Columns.Add("name_y_data", typeof(String));
DataRow drresult;
foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Columns.Count / 2; i++)
    {
        drresult = result.NewRow();
        drresult["datestamp"] = datarow["datestamp"];
        drresult["name_x_data"] = datarow["name_X_" + i];
        drresult["name_y_data"] = datarow["name_Y_" + i];
        result.Rows.Add(drresult);
    }
}
```